# How can I control admob Interstitial Ads on Android?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I want to add Interstitial ads to my game. An example code I found works fine, but the problem is it appears just once at the startup of my app. I want to control the ad's appeareance and call my displayInterstitial() method in other classes, like from my GameScreen class. How can I call ads from any other class?

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class BannerExample extends Activity {

  private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

  }

  // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
  public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a facade to achieve this. Make sure you make the  calls from the UI thread.  The following should work :

Define an interface for example MyAdListener.java:

```
public interface MyAdListener{
public void displayInterstitial();
}
```

In your game's main activity, implement the interface:

```
public class BannerExample extends Activity implements MyAdListener{
   private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

  }

  // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.

@Override
  public void displayInterstitial() {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) interstitial.show();
    }
  });
}



Then finally in your game screen's class:

public class GameScreen extends View implements Runnable{
    MyAdListener myAdListener;

    public GameScreen(Context context){
    myAdListener = (MyAdListener)context;
    //display the interstitial ad
    myAdListener.displayInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: The last Thing to call it on my game screen doesn't work for me because i extend and implements much other classes and I have an different constructor and im unable to get my context is there an other method to call it from anywhere?

Comment: I get this weird erros :( 03-12 03:22:32.778: W/System.err(17810): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.musti.sario.util.MyAdListener.displayInterstitial()' on a null object reference

Comment: How is your Game screen's constructor defined? Please post your GameScreen class

Comment: i want it call from anywhere i can't change every constructor from the class i want to call a interstitial ad is it possible to use another way to call a ad?

Comment: All your classes must have access to the context in one way or the other. If they don't you can use static calls. Just make the fields static and use getApplicationContext().runOnUIThread(){} inside those classes

Comment: You can try with static calls then. Make the fields static and use getApplicationContext().runOnUIThread(){} instead. Nevertheless, the game screen and other non-activity classes should have access to the context regardless. Check the stack, where they get initialized, you'd have access to the context